# can I lock the internet account settings on mac osx

Tags: macos, sync, gmail

On my office mac, I am using my personal gmail account to keep my contacts.

The computer is occasionally used by colleagues, so I do not want to sync my emails or notes. They are personal.

Even when I setup the google account as a CardDav account, It is displayed as a standard email account in the internet accounts settings. Here I can choose to sync the mails or the notes without any authorization.

In some other sections of the settings app, there is a padlock in the left bottom and you need to unlock this first to make any changes in that section.

Can I have the same for the internet accounts section, or is there a way to sync the contacts but not the notes, or the mails with my gmail account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need a separate piece of software to sync just your contacts without leaving your mail and notes just as easily accessible.

If possible, I would just use another account at work; personal accounts have a nasty reputation for trouble in the workplace.

It's easy to export your contacts from your gmail account and import them to another account (https://support.google.com/mail/topic/3397465), and [if necessary] you can set your personal device to sync with your work account [instead of the other way around].

Comment: After many trials, I now have a gmail work account for the contacts and calendar. I also use it to send and receive mail through my work email address. This way I can access all three (mail, contacts, calendar) from my personal computer, phone, tablet and my personal info is out of the scene. For this, I had to use gmail app on the iPhone and iPad. I am not very happy with this as I like the native mail app on iOS better.